# How to add a progress bar in a navbar with bulma?

Tags: html, bulma

I am using [bulma](http://bulma.io) CSS framework to build a webapp. 
As stated in the question, I want to add a progress bar in a bottom navbar, but the progress bar doesn't show up. Any help would  be appreciated :

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   

<div class="navbar is-success" role="player" aria-label="main player">
    <div class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
            <div class="navbar-item">
                <progress class="progress" value="15" max="100">15></progress>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run that snippet in full screen I see a progress bar. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you post an image of the desired layout?

Comment: Hi, but where do you see the progress bar ?  I want to display a music player similar to soundcloud. I already have the controls set, but I cannot display in the progress bar in the navbar ?

Comment: I see the progress bar at the left side of the navbar in full view mode. Do you not see this?